# How to make a heatmap of Gene ontology terms

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm trying to do a heatmap with the -log(FDR) of the gene ontologies of differentially expressed genes of two genotypes ("rsh3" and "iron"). In these two columns "rsh3" and "iron" are written the -log(FDR) of the GO terms.

I don't understand whether I'm miswriting the code or I'm wrongly displaying my data in the dataframe.

Just in case I'm not being clear, this is how my dataframe looks like:

[image]

I tried this code:

```r
library(ggplot2)

heat <- read_excel("directory/heat_final.xlsx")

heat_matrix <- as.matrix(heat)

ggplot(heat, aes(x = factor(c("rsh3", "iron")), y = GO_term)) + 
  geom_tile()
```

And i get this error:

```r
> ggplot(heat, aes(x = factor(c("rsh3", "iron")), y = GO_term)) + 
+   geom_tile()
Error in `geom_tile()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (288)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `x`
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I am actually trying to get a heatmap that looks like the Figure 3 of this paper:

[image]
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/21580103.2020.1801524

Comment: Could you add a portion of the actual data, so your code is reproducible?
`dput(head(heat.matrix, 10))` or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that in `ggplot(aes())`, `x` should be a column name where the column contains the genotypes, not a factor containing column names.

A side-note is that `ggplot()` is expecting the data in a data.frame, not a matrix, so your conversion is at best useless (will be reverted immediately), or could make things worse.

So, what you need is a data.frame with a column `GO_term`, that you can map to `y`, and a column `genotype`, that you can map to `x`. And of course, a column that you can map to the `fill` color, let's call it `log_FDR`.

This means you need to take the columns corresponding to the genotypes, and collapse them to a single column, to make your data [tidy](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html), e.g. with `pivot_longer()`.

So using dummy data to illustrate, here is a reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

# dummy data
heat <- tribble(~GO_term, ~rsh3, ~iron, ~mutant2,
                "GO1", 1.81, 1.86, 2.5,
                "GO2", 3.2, 0, 1)

heat |>
  select(GO_term, rsh3, iron) |>
  pivot_longer(-GO_term,
               names_to = "genotype",
               values_to = "log_FDR") |>
  ggplot(aes(x = genotype, y = GO_term, fill = log_FDR)) + 
  geom_tile()
```